# Gitlab-CI and WKHTML: reading URLs from a text file and publishing PDF. Unexpected error, job failed, exit code 1

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, wkhtmltopdf

I have a website that uses the generator Jekyll. I regularly upload its content on Gitlab pages thanks to a gitlab-ci.yaml file. However, I would like to create a pdf from the published pages and integrate it in the CI file.

I use wkhtmltopdf and my urls are listed in a text file.The pipeline starts on gitlab.com and just outputs an error message without further information:

> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00 ERROR:
> Job failed: exit code 1

I struggle with this problem since a long time now, that's why I'm looking for help. Thanks a lot for your help!

The relevant part in my gitlab-ci file is here:

```
convert-pdf:
  stage: build
  image: michaelperrin/wkhtmltopdf:latest
  script:
    - xargs -a ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/pdf-generation/myurls.txt sh -c 'wkhtmltopdf $@ --javascript-delay 30000 --dpi 300 -s A4 --disable-smart-shrinking --zoom 1.0 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/output/result.pdf'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/output/*
    expire_in: 1 week
```

And my whole CI file is here:

```
image: ruby:2.7

stages:
  - build
  - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

pages:
  stage: test

  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "gh-pages"'


convert-pdf:
  stage: build
  image: michaelperrin/wkhtmltopdf:latest
  script:
    - xargs -a ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/generation-pdf/myurls.txt sh -c 'wkhtmltopdf $@ --javascript-delay 30000 --dpi 300 -s A4 --disable-smart-shrinking --zoom 1.0 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/output/result.pdf'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/output/*
    expire_in: 1 week

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "gh-pages"'

test_variable:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$CI_PROJECT_DIR" # calls a predefined variable
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or your own self-hosted GitLab instance? If using gitlab.com, do you use your own runners or the Shared Runners provided by GitLab?

Comment: I use gitlab.com and the shared runner provided by Gitlab.

Comment: In that case I would [open an Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new?issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=) since only the GitLab admins can see what's happening in the runners. This doesn't appear to be an issue with your pipeline definition/project.